# Why new Request class from Mootools does nothing... or ignores me?

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools

I'm working on a component for Joomla 1.7, and Joomla 1.7 works with Mootools 1.3. Before that, the correct way in mootools was Ajax class. But in Mootools, as I read, I must use Request class.

Ok, when I try to use the Request class and take a look with Google Inspector debuging step by step the Request definition and Request send() call. I can see that, it execs the send but it does nothing (ignores onSuccess, ignores OnException, etc).

And if I look on chrome javascript console there's nothing.

```
function addValue(value) {
    var id = $('selectedval').getProperty('value');
    var url = 'index.php?option=com_kaltura&controller=fieldsmanager&task=additem&tmpl=component';
    var req = new Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'value': value
        },
        onRequest: function(event, xhr) {alert('gogogo'); },
        onFailure: function(xhr) { alert('failure'.xhr); },
        onException: function(test) {alert(test); },
        onSuccess: function(data) {
            loadFieldList(data);
        }
    });
    req.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the api has changed from 1.1x to 1.2 -> Request now takes a single argument object that overloads all options you need, INCLUDING url - which used to be arguments[0] before.

In other words - move the url from there into a property of the options object:

```
new Request({
    url: url,
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        'id': id,
        'value': value
    },
    onRequest: function(event, xhr) {alert('gogogo'); },
    onFailure: function(xhr) { alert('failure'.xhr); },
    onException: function(test) {alert(test); },
    onSuccess: function(data) {
        loadFieldList(data);
    }
}).send();
```